# Stripping style attribute from paragraph tags

Tags: php, html, regex

I've found this regex that strips style attributes out of tags.

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $_POST['content']);
```

It works perfectly but I'm trying to find a solution that strips the style only out of paragraph `<p>` tags:

```
<h1 style="font: times">Hello</h1>
<p style="font: verdana">World</p>
```

would become

```
<h1 style="font: times">Hello</h1>
<p>World</p>
```

I've tried modifying the regex myself but I can't wrap my head around this and my regex just fails.

Comment: I recommend using a proper HTML library. This nesting problem is particularly hard to do with a regular expression - it doesn't help that <P> elements do *not* need to be explicitly closed.

Comment: @user2864740 I understand and I may take a look at a library to use. In this case though I can guarantee that they will always be closed.

Comment: Asking for *which* library to use - likely. But that is what a search engine and research is for. (Once a library is picked, then a question about it's usage would be more appropriate.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### (*SKIP)(*F) and `\K`

With all the disclaimers about using regex to parse html, you can use this regex:

```
<(?!p)[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|<p[^>]*\Kstyle\s*=\s*"[^"]*"
```

See the substitutions at the bottom of **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yZ7jX6/6)**.

**Sample PHP Code**

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~<(?!p)[^>]*>|<p[^>]*\Kstyle\s*=\s*"[^"]*"~',
                          '', 
                          $yourstring);
```

**Explanation**

This problem is a classic case of the technique explained in this question to ["regex-match a pattern, excluding..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)

The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `<non-p tags>` then deliberately fails, after which the engine skips to the next position in the string. The right side matches styles, and we know they are the right ones because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

**Reference**

- [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)
- [Article about matching a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Comment: FYI added explanation. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `p\b` in the captured group to make sure only `p` is selected (but not `pre`):

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<p\b[^>]*) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $_POST['content']);
```

Comment: @zx81, but the capture group is added back in?

Comment: @zx81, I mean replaced with `$1`

Comment: I totally missed that. Sorry, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using a regular expression and make use out of the right [**tool**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for the job...

```
$html = <<<DATA
<h1 style="font: times">Hello</h1>
<h2 style="font: times">Hello</h2>
<p style="font: verdana">World</p>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument;  
$dom->loadHTML($html); // Load your HTML

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);  

foreach ($xpath->query('//p[@style]') as $node) {
    $node->removeAttribute('style'); 
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output

```
<h1 style="font: times">Hello</h1>
<h2 style="font: times">Hello</h2>
<p>World</p>
```